# Firebase Messaging packages is not working after Package Update?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
    _firebaseMessaging.*configure*( onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("\n\n on1Message: ${message.toString()}");
    Map<String, dynamic> object = json.decode(
        message['data']['notification'].toString());

    print(
        '\n\n Object==${message['data']}\n\n object===$object');
    object['work'] = 'updateCount';
    Stream<Map<String, dynamic>> stream =
        Stream.value(object);

    streamController.addStream(stream);

    print("\n\n object ---> ${object}");
```

Error in Console Log----------------------------------------------------------------
722:24: Error: The method 'configure' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseMessaging'.

- 'FirebaseMessaging' is from 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart' ('/E:/flutterSDK/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-9.1.0/lib/firebase_messaging.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'configure'.
  _firebaseMessaging.configure
  (    ^^^^^^^^^

configure() method is not working after the update of the Package of Firebase Cloud Messaging. I tried different solution from the stack overflow but nothing works.
What Should I do in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new FirebaseMessaging is a little bit different.
Here are two interesting links:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/

After adding firebase to the App, this is what I do (NotificationDetails is a class I wrote to show the details of the Notification. You can write you own class.):

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routes: {
      '/': (context) =>  AppStarter(),
      '/message': (context) => NotificationDetails(),
      },
     ),
    );
   }



class AppStarter extends StatefulWidget{
   @override
   _AppStarterState createState() => _AppStarterState();
  }



class _AppStarterState extends State<AppStarter>
   {

     FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

    Future<void> showMeMyToken()
    async {
      var myToken = await messaging.getToken();
      print("My Token is: " + myToken.toString());
    }


    @override
    void initState() {
       super.initState();

       showMeMyToken();

      FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((value) {
       if(value != null)
        {
          Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context){return NotificationDetails();},
          settings: RouteSettings(arguments: value.data,),
         ),
        );
       }
     });


     FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {


        if (message.notification != null) {
           print('Message on Foreground: ${message.notification}');
              }
         });


      FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message)
       {
         Navigator.push(
           context,
           MaterialPageRoute(
               builder: (context) {return NotificationDetails();},
               settings: RouteSettings(arguments: message.data,)
          ),
        );
     });

     FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
   }


   @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

      return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Just a Test',
        
        home: AppHome(),
       );
      }
   }




   Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
     await Firebase.initializeApp();

      print("Handling a background message :-): ${message.data}");
      //Here you can do what you want with the message :-)
     }
```

Comment: Can you help me with this Error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66952211/flutter-signed-build-of-android-is-not-opening-but-all-the-debug-builds-are-work