# Flutter - Get notifications from FCM, with the new FlutterFire

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to get notifications that I send from Firebase, in my code, as was done in the old `.configure()` method. But as the flutter has undergone a recent update, I'm not able to get the notification that arrives from the API, as I end up getting this error:

> D/FLTFireMsgReceiver(30170): broadcast received for message

This is my code:

```
class PushConfig {    
  RemoteNotification notification;
  AndroidNotification android;

  Future<dynamic> fcmMessageReceiver() async {
  RemoteMessage  message= await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((m) {
    if(m.notification != null){
      print("NOTIF: ${notification}");
    }
   });

  print("MESSAGE $message");
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66919969/firebase-messaging-packages-is-not-working-after-package-update/66936581#66936581

Comment: I was able to receive the notification, thank you very much for your help. : D

Comment: Could you then close the question?